# moderncv: bullet points between phone/email/social

Tags: titles, moderncv

In the image below there's a bullet point in between the phone number and the email address. I'd like to know how to remove it.

[image: moderncv]

I'm using the banking template for `moderncv`.

Comment: Do you want to remove just that one bullet or all of them?

Comment: The bullet point is changed to 3 spaces with:
```
\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{~~~}
```
if: tex --version
```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bullet is stored in the macro `\makeheaddetailssymbol` and is inserted between every element of the title. By default it's defined to be

```
\newcommand*{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
%   internal command to add an element to the footer
%   it collects the elements in a temporary box, and checks when to flush the box
```

You could update this to

```
\renewcommand*{\makeheaddetailssymbol}{~~~}
```

to insert 3 spaces between elements, or however you wish.

Comment: For me this yields the following error: ``\maketitlesymbol undefined. \renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}``. Why does this happen?

Comment: The nice people on the #latex IRC channel pointed out that using ``makeheaddetailssymbol`` instead of ``maketitlesymbol`` works!